# Auto Build using VSS

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build, visual-sourcesafe

How can I make my auto build in VSS? It should get the latest files from VSS and build the code using Visual Studio 2005 (VSS does not provide any build facility) at a scheduled time (like in the mid night).

Answer (score 4):

Use [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET). It can do your automated builds, run your unit tests, gather statistics and it is open source, so you don't have to buy a license!

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur inputs.
I have to only use VSS 2005 and VS2005. Can I write some code or batch file for automated build at a scheduled time?

Comment: CruiseControl.NET is programmed, so you can do the same. In the end though, using an existing product is probably much cheaper and has less risks than coding it up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think VSS is capable of such things.

What you're talking about is a job for a Continuous Integration tool like [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/). Here you can specify when to check out the sources and build the application. Additionally you can configure it to run Unit Tests for the application or to check your code by FxCop.

For a run Cruise Control will give you detailed information about every step, so you can see where you had problems or be happy that you had none at all.

I already tested Cruise Control a time ago. It's a little difficult to set up, but when it finally runs, it's absolutely great. You should give it a try.

**UPDATE:**

You said, you only want to use VSS and VS for your builds. So probably you should get in touch with [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx). With MSBuild-scipts it should be possible to check out code from your repository and build it automatically. The build-script is run from Windows task planer, so it would be launched whenever you wanted it.

For further information you should dig into the MSBuild documentation. I'm pretty sure you can achieve all you want just by MSBuild-scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur inputs. I have to only use VSS 2005 and VS2005. Can I write some code or batch file for automated build at a scheduled time?

Answer (score 2):

As stated above VSS does not offer any build type functionality, that would be [TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/dd408382.aspx).

If you are stuck and are unable to use any helpful build tools like [Cruise Control](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/),[NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) (Both free and Open Source by the way) or get deeper into [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479(VS.80).aspx), which is available to you with Visual Studio you could write a batch file to do a get from VSS (there is a command line interface for doing that) and then use MSBuild, or [devenv.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z(VS.80).aspx)(I really don't recommend using DevEnv.exe) to actually compile your solutions and projects.  So just using batch files and the windows scheduler to control when you build you can create a basic automated build system.

Answer (score 1):

Cruise Control is very hard to set up. Use TeamCity. It is very easy and powerful. [JetBrain TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

And it has free Professional Edition.

Comment: I have to only use VSS 2005 and VS2005. Can I write some code or batch file for automated build at a scheduled time?

Comment: there is tool for that. Try to learn MSBuild, MSBuild VSS task and Windows sheduler (AT command)
http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Comment: hm. I meen there is NO tool in VS for that. You should craft it yourself using tools I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned the easiest way of doing things is to set up [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). This can watch your source control fro changes and then automatically build your solution files directly.

If you must use VSS only then you need to write some sort of script that does the following:

1. Check out source from VSS.
2. Build the solution file.
3. Report on the results.

I would reccomend MSBuild for this as it can at least build your solution files natively. for the vss integration and the reporting the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) Will be very useful

Of course You then need to find a way of triggering your build on vss checkin. I do not know if this is possible.