# how to detect changes in SourceSafe projects (automatically)?

Tags: continuous-integration, visual-sourcesafe

I want to write a simple batch file that will continually check for updates across several VSS projects, and trigger automatic builds whenever any developer checks in code. Is there a command line option to do this with the SS command ?

I've looked at the list of commands/options but don't see one that polls for updates:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/003ssz4z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use auto build tools like CruiseControl .NET.
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Visual+Source+Safe+Source+Control+Block

You can also check the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170062/auto-build-using-vss) regarding auto build with VSS.